# accessing user input within the value of an object literal

Tags: javascript, object, object-literal

These forums are amazing and the contributors I've been helped by are really talented. So I keep coming back everytime I can't solve my own problems or am not understanding a programming concept. This is certainly one of the latter times!

With the help I've received so far, I've managed to develop a complicated form in which the end user will mostly click a series of checkboxes and enter some data into a few textfields. The result of these actions will populate some textboxes with various text, based on the aforementioned actions.

The text that populates the textareas is referenced within a few object literals by each checkbox. This works just fine and the site is quite useable.

In my object literals, I have name:value pairs in which the 'value' is a string of text. I've been trying to include a variable within some name:value pairs to no success. This always breaks the script because the variable is never defined / has a 'null' value on page load.

For example,

Instead of

```
    var example = {
var1:'some string',
var2:'some other string'
  }
```

I tried,

```
var somevariable = document.getElementById('someId');
var example = {
var1: 'some string' + somevariable + 'some other bit',
var2: 'some other string'
}
```

**My question is whether including a variable referenced elsewhere in the script can be incorporated within the name:value pair in an object literal?**

For reference (and because it is a rather long script), my site is: http://www.hematogones.com/bmbiopsies.html.

Comment: You can include variables in the value of an object literal. In your specific example you have a couple issues: Should be `getElementById` and I assume `someId` is a text field and if so, you want to do something like: `document.getElementById('someId').value`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. Yes, 'somevariable' does refer to the value of a textfield. On page load, the text field is blank, and I'm assuming that since the object literal is looking for the variable value - a blank field is returning null. Do you think this is why my console tells me the error is the null value?

Comment: I noticed your edit on the `getElementById`, but your 'b' is still lowercase, so again that could still be syntax. In general, a textfield's value will either be the empty string or whatever has been typed into the textfield.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick with an object literal is that it is evaluated immediately; there is no "easy" way to delay the value you get.

```
var x = "Alice";
var obj = { greeting: "Hello, " + x + "." };
console.log(obj.greeting);  // "Hello, Alice."
x = "Bob";
console.log(obj.greeting);  // "Hello, Alice."
obj = { greeting: "Hello, " + x + "." };
console.log(obj.greeting);  // "Hello, Bob."
```

**Something to come back to later:**

If you really really *really* need to put a variable into a string literal you define later, you could create an inline function. This way, instead of `obj.greeting` being a simple string, it is a function that you call (which will look like `obj.greeting()`).This means that instead of the string value being calculated when you declare your object, it will be declared when you call the function. This is a very powerful feature of Javascript called "closures" and you could spend all day learning about the behaviors, expected and unexpected, that you get with them.

```
var x = "Alice";
var obj = { greeting: function() { return "Hello, " + x + "." }};
console.log(obj.greeting());  // "Hello, Alice."
x = "Bob";
console.log(obj.greeting());  // "Hello, Bob."
```

Comment: Okay. Then, on page load - the variable I want to include in my name:value pair may not have been created further down in the html - because the Object literal is immediately evaluated? If instead `var x = "Alice";` were `var x = document.getElementById('someId').value;`, the function would not work because the input with id='someId' came after the object was evaluated - correct?

Comment: @user1837608 Right. If you were to say `var b = { value: a }; var a = 20;` the first statement would be an error because the second statement hasn't been evaluated yet (so `a` does not exist yet).

Comment: Thanks Jeff. I didn't see this causal relationship error in my convoluted website - but it makes sense with the simple example you give. I'll have to spend some time to learn about closures - but I'm getting the feeling that I won't be able to incorporate your second example in the structure of my site. Doh!

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes. Here's a working example:

```
var myStr = "world";
var obj = { var1: "hello " + myStr };
console.log(obj.var1); // Outputs: hello world
```

As I mentioned in my comment, your specific example has a couple syntax errors, so perhaps just fixing those will correct your issue.

Comment: Thanks. I rushed my syntax on the example above, but on my site everything works fine. Jeff's example above suggests that I am calling  a variable in my object literal that doesn't exist, due to the immediate evaluation of my object.

Comment: That very well could be the problem. If you can create a more concrete simple example we can help pinpoint the issue further. You can try to use http://jsfiddle.net/ to create that example if the code is a little lengthy.